# How can I run single test cases via Android's ant build script?

Tags: android, testing, ant, functional-testing

Android's standard `build.xml` comes with complete support for executing functional test cases  on devices and emulators via the `test` target. But this target always executes all test cases in a test project; how can I instruct it to run only a single test case, for debugging reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adb shell "start instrument -w -e class package_name/class_name package_name/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"`

Comment: I wrapped this into a custom target. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created my own target in `custom_rules.xml` that abstracts a little from user674199's answer:

```
<target name="test-single" depends="-test-project-check" description="Runs a single test case, given with -DclassToTest=package.path.to.Class">
    <run-tests-helper>
        <extra-instrument-args>
            <arg value="-e" />
               <arg value="class" />
               <arg value="${classToTest}" />
        </extra-instrument-args>
    </run-tests-helper>
</target>
```

That serves my purposes quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas answer is a bit deprecated or just not working because of error:

```
testSingle:
     [echo] Running tests ...
     [exec] /system/bin/sh: ${test.runner}: bad substitution
```

If you see original `test` target in Android SDK `build.xml` you see that some other required properties are set before, so here is a working target for me:

```
<!-- custom test target to perform specific test only -->
<target
    name="testSingle"
    depends="-test-project-check"
    description="Runs a single test case, given with -DtestClass=package.path.to.Class">

     <property name="test.runner" value="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
     <property name="tested.project.absolute.dir" location="${tested.project.dir}" />

    <!-- Application package of the tested project extracted from its manifest file -->
     <xpath input="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml"
             expression="/manifest/@package" output="tested.project.app.package" />

    <run-tests-helper>
        <extra-instrument-args>
           <arg value="-e" />
             <arg value="class" />
              <arg value="${testClass}" />
        </extra-instrument-args>
    </run-tests-helper>
</target>
```

Here is how i run it:

> ant instrument testSingle -DtestClass=com.company.tests.SomeTest

where `com.company.tests.SomeTest` is full test class name.